# How can I dynamically create input fields to post back to my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Not sure if the question makes sense. Here is what I would like to do *ideally*. I have a database table with templates of text like this:

```
Line managed |amount| individuals.

Won |currency| |value| of new business in |quarter|.

Responsible for P&L worth |currency| |value|.

Managed |numberOf| external clients across |territory|.
```

This is exactly how they are stored currently in a lookup table. I can change this if need be, but I needed to start with something.

I need to create a page where the user can navigate through a list of these 'templates' by name and they can fill it out like this:

```
Won [currency select list] [value text input] of 
new business in [quarter text input]
                                                 [submit button]
```

I set up the page so far to loop through the categories and then templates like so:

```
<div class="row tab-v3">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="statementCats">
            @foreach(var cat in Model.StatementCategories)
            {
            <li class="active"><a href="#@cat.Id" data-toggle="tab">@cat.Name</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="tab-content" id="statementTabs">
            @foreach(var cat in Model.StatementCategories)
            {
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="@cat.Id">
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var tmpl in Model.StatementTemplates.Where(tmpl => tmpl.StatementCategory != null && tmpl.StatementCategory.Id == cat.Id))
                    {
                    <li>@tmpl.Name</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So here is where I am getting hung up:

1. The template text can hav 1-infinite number of input fields.
2. I would like to post the template Id (so I know which text template I am using) and then the values from the text inputs. I don't know how I can generate all these inputs and assign them id's that I will know of in advance to handle in the controller.
3. I need to avoid hard coding values since one requirement is that I can add new templates the the database and I will not need to add a place on the page to account for the newly added one, it should automatically make it based off the db stuff.

**Am i heading down the right path here?**

If so, can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction of how I can create these form field dynamically but in a way where I can reliably do some magic on the controller and say "oh ok, it is this template, I should expect x number of input, which are a,b and c"?

**Edit, forgot to post the viewmodel**

ViewModel:

```
public class CareerStatementsViewModel
{
    //user specific statements
    public List<UserStatement> UserStatements { get; set; }
    //Simple name and id table
    public List<StatementCategory> StatementCategories { get; set; }
    //has the statement template, id, and associated category_id
    public List<StatementTemplate> StatementTemplates { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class of `Answer`s specific to your needs.

```
public class Answer
{
    public int questionId { get; set; }
    public string answer { get; set; }
    // Anything else you might want or need
}
```

Then create a `List<Answer>` on your model coming in from your web page. You will have to build the list in your web page's submit method, probably manually.

Comment: I still see this as having to write out the text and input manually for each template. I can see how I can post back to one place possibly, but it does not solve any of the razor markup issues.